# How to filter for multiple values with multiple JOINs

Tags: sql, mysql, join

This is a vague title, so please correct it if you can think of a better one.

Consider these 4 tables:

**products**: id (int), name, msrp, etc...

**subproducts**: id (int), product_id (int), name (varchar)

**subproducts_properties**: id (int), subproduct_id (int), property_id (int)

**subproducts_properties_values**: subproducts_properties_id (int), value (varchar)

So the basic idea here is that a single product can have multiple subproducts (models), a single subproduct can have multiple properties (or specs), and a single property for a subproduct can have multiple values.

Now imagine that there is a product that has multiple subproducts which have multiple properties which have multiple values. In particular, this product has a subproduct that has these properties:

> **Property 1** - property_id: 1; value = '.17 HMR';
>
> **Property 2** - property_id: 22; value = 'Bolt';

Where `property_id 1` has a name `Caliber` and `property_id 2` has a name `Action` (think: guns).

What this product *doesn't* have is a subproduct containing a property with `property_id=1` and `value='5.56 mm NATO'`.

The user has drop-down boxes where he can select multiple filter sets based on unique values. So if a user selects a `Caliber` of `.17 HMR` and an `Action` of `Bolt`, he should expect to see our product, but when he pulls back `Bolt` and a `Caliber` of, say, `5.56 mm NATO`, he should see *no* products because our product doesn't match both filters.

So...given this information, I would like to pull back all *products* (one product per row) in the database and filter by multiple property values. My current attempt goes like this:

```
SELECT p.*, m.name as manufacturer_name, pt.name as product_type_name, COUNT(DISTINCT com.id) AS num_reviews, ROUND(AVG(com.rating), 1) as rating, pi.image_thumb 
FROM products p 
        LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturer_id=m.id 
        LEFT JOIN product_types pt ON p.product_type_id=pt.id 
        LEFT JOIN comments com ON p.id=com.object_id AND com.object_group = 'com_products' AND com.level=0 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                SELECT product_id, thumb_path as image_thumb 
                FROM products_images pi 
                ORDER BY ordering ASC 
            ) AS pi ON p.id=pi.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN subproducts sp ON p.id=sp.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN subproducts_properties spp ON sp.id=spp.subproduct_id 
        LEFT JOIN subproducts_properties_values sppv ON spp.id=sppv.sp_id 
WHERE p.deleted != 1 AND p.published=1 
            AND ( 
                        IF(spp.property_id=1, IF(sppv.value='5.56 mm NATO',1,0), 0) = 1 
                    OR IF(spp.property_id=22, IF(sppv.value='Bolt',1,0), 0) = 1
                ) 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 12
```

The part to focus on is the last `AND` in the `WHERE` clause where I attempt to get the filters going. Notice, too, that I have a `GROUP BY` in order to be able to perform aggregate functions on other tables. This particular query will pull back our product because of the `OR` inside that last `AND`, but I would like to set it up so it doesn't pull it back in this case, but does pull it back if instead of `sppv.value='5.56 mm NATO'` there is `sppv.value='.17 HMR'` (which is a value for our subproduct).

I've tried putting an AND in there instead, but it doesn't return anything because each value has its own row in the sppv table.

Please help! I'm totally lost for what to do here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: EAV is like regexps: after you've decided you want to solve your issue with EAV - you have 2 issues.

Comment: @zerkms I'm a bit of a novice in the theory behind this. Could you perhaps expound a bit?

Comment: @treeface: I meant that EAV (the way of storing data) is just looks very flexible and nice, but when you need to write some more or less complex query - you'll get pain. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx Note on the last words: "I hope you found this guide useful and that it discourages you from using an EAV design"

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking so forgive me if what i say is retarded. I'm guessing you want a row returning if your gun is a '5.56 mm NATO' AND it's a 'Bolt' (has both properties)? As you said if you change your OR there to an AND you get no rows. This is because a single row can't have 2 values. You can join to the property table twice. on the first you check prop=1 value='5.56 mm NATO' on the second join check for 'Bolt'. If you properties are dynamic however you may have to do some other jiggery pokery.

Comment: Also just out of curiosity why do you have a subselect on product images when you can just do this as a join? The subselect plan should be more inefficient.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you for the link! I hope I didn't sound like one of those guys who gets angry when told that they're asking the wrong question. I very much appreciate having my previous notions turned upside down...especially when they're misguided. While The Scrum Meister solved my specific problem, you've saved me from many headaches in the future!

Comment: @user364939 I subselect the product images because it has to be in a specific order. If you mean that there is a way to do that ORDER BY without the subselect, I'd be very happy to hear it. On a side note (as a bizarre coincidence), I'm trying to get this girl I've been seeing into Dr. Who. I read your comment last night when I was hanging out with her and I had totally forgotten where I first heard "jiggery pokery". The episode we watched last night was season 1 episode 2. When I heard it my mind exploded. she thought I was a bit crazy ;-). Btw...is that a technical term, jiggery pokery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a Having - Count - If instead of the where:

```
WHERE p.deleted != 1 AND p.published=1 
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(IF(spp.property_id = 1 AND sppv.value='5.56 mm NATO',1,NULL)) > 0 
       AND COUNT(IF(spp.property_id=22 AND sppv.value='Bolt',1,NULL)) > 0
ORDER BY p.created DESC
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing, sir. You've just made my day!